# Wipe out Amalek Round 2

Tags: king-david, amalek, king-saul

Shaul was commanded to wipe out Amalek and Dovid would've built the beis hamikdosh after conquering the surrounding nations but Hashem wanted Shlomo to do it.
Destroying Amalek is a preparation for building the beis hamikdosh.
Haman came from Agag so they weren't wiped out yet. Why wasn't Dovid commanded to finish Shaul's job?

Comment: Related: "[How did Dovid Hamelech kill Amaleikim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13909/1368)"

Comment: According to the answer to the question above, maybe all the “bad amaelkites” were killed by Shaul and the rest that were left were good so David didn’t have to kill them, but generations later they became corrupted and evil and hence you have Haman

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13910/why-did-none-of-the-later-kings-of-israel-destroy-amalek